# active inside TabSet's Tab condition not working Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, typescript1.4, angular-ui-tabset

Hi There i am facing problem here that even though the condition is validated in if condition in below code the same code is not working in tab's Active Attribute iam not getting why the code is not working in active where as the code works fine in ng if inside  please help me

```
<div>
        <tabset>
            <tab heading = "ABC" active="$parent.newcoverCtrl.assessmentSelectedTab=='ABC'">
            </tab>
            <tab heading = "XYZ" active="$parent.newcoverCtrl.assessmentSelectedTab=='XYZ'">
            </tab>

        </tabset>
    </div>

    <h1>
       {{$parent.CarCtrl.assessmentSelectedTab}} this is  what selected
       <h1 ng-if="$parent.CarCtrl.assessmentSelectedTab=='ABC'">
           ABC
       </h1>
        <h1 ng-if="$parent.CarCtrl.assessmentSelectedTab=='XYZ'">
            XYZ
        </h1>

    </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution that 
instead of putting condition in active attribute put the condition in controller and assign one boolean variable to it and put it in active attribute this will work fine

thanks stackoverflow :)